# PHP: xml_parse and xml_set_element_handler

Tags: php, xml, hhvm

I have this code:

```
<?php
function start_elem($parser,$name,$attribs) {
   echo "<$name>";
}
function end_elem($parser,$name)
{
   echo "</$name>";
}

$parser=xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option($parser,XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING,0);
xml_set_element_handler($parser,"start_elem","end_elem");
$buf = '<F>';
echo xml_parse($parser,$buf,strlen($buf)==0);
```

Expected output:

```
<F>1
```

Actual output:

```
 1
```

Does anyone know why start_elem() is not called here?

PS:

```
php --version
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u7 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 08:42:07)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v2.0.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2012, by mOo
```

HHVM in comparison outputs:

```
<F>1
```

HHVM Version:

```
HipHop VM 3.1.0 (rel)
Compiler: tags/HHVM-3.1.0-0-g71ecbd8fb5e94b2a008387a2b5e9a8df5c6f5c7b
Repo schema: 88ae0db264d72ec2e2eb22ab25d717214aee568b
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1391

Comment: POSIX textfiles are expected to have a line-ending. in your buffer that line-ending is missing which is why the element that is opened but never closed before reaching EOF (EOB) is the cutted from the input sequence as data is missing. you could also just append a space or another different character that would shift the internal state of the parser at least by one character making it aware that your string should be an element. Your input BTW is ***not*** XML. You probably would like to make it self-closing like `<F/>` which is supported by that parser.

Comment: @hakre Thanks for your input. That could be a possibility for this issue. I don't have control over the input (it is part of the PHP/Java Bridge), so I know it is not XML. The main issue is, that PHP and HHVM treat the input differently.

Comment: fix the XML with Tidy first (or just append a LF, you can do that easyly). Whether or not HHVM treat this non-XML different I'd say is more of esoteric nature as the data is not XML. You can report this for strictness, but I could reproduce this behavior with PHP and HHVM so I don't think this is actually a HHVM issue.

Comment: No, it is not possible to fix the XML with Tidy since it is part of a data communication protocol I have no control over. You get the same output with PHP and HHVM? If so, which versions were you using?

Comment: If Tidy would change too much, try with just adding a LF if the last char isn't an LF. That normally does work with protocols (you mileage may vary). I was using PHP 5.4 something on some windowze box, next time I'm on it and I think about it, I'll fetch all versions, incl. from the extension.

Comment: Have you tried in HHVM as well? Because the problem is the different handling in PHP and HHVM, not how PHP handles it.

Comment: Setup a git repo with a .travis file that shows your case (mocked, no need to show secret data). This might shed more light of what you're running against in integration. I'm sure there is an easy way to circumvent the difference between HHVM and core PHP data handling as well as such a test-case would help HHVM maintainers.

Comment: I currently have no idea how to setup a .travis file but I will check. The main issue however is, that HHVM and PHP do behave differently and that should be avoided rather than cirumventing the difference between HHVM and PHP. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: It's simple, you just say which PHP versions to run the code / script, and you can say HHVM next to PHP 5.2 up to 5.6. see http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/

Comment: Github issue on HHVM here: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1391

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the output in [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).  The tag is being parsed by the browser and ignored; the above function will convert the tags to displayable.

For example:

```php
echo htmlspecialchars(xml_parse($parser, $buf, strlen($buf) == 0));
```

Comment: This has unfortunately nothing to do with the question I asked. The difference boils down to a different implementation of the XML parser in HHVM and PHP, and it seems it won't be fixed in HHVM.